# Multi-channel Lattice Recursive Least Squares

Tags: algorithm, matlab, regression, least-squares, noise-reduction

I'm trying to implement multi-channelt lattice RLS, i.e. the recursive least squares algorithm which performs noise cancellation with multiple inputs, but a single 'desired output'.

I have the basic RLS algorithm working with multiple components, but it's too inefficient and memory intensive for my purpose.
Wikipedia has an excellent example of lattice RLS, which works great.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter
However, the sources it cites do not go into much detail on how to extend this to the multi-channel case, and re-doing the full derivation is a bit beyond me.

Does anyone know a good source which describes or implements this algorithm in the multi-channel case? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you look at http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~jpg/papers/conf/conftele03.pdf? And in general papers by http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~jpg/papers/ ?

Comment: I didn't see that particular paper, but have tried to implement many similar ones. Unfortunately, papers tend to have some notational ambiguity, unclear initialization, skipped steps, or even minor mistakes. Available code, or pseudo-code tends to avoid this, but unfortunately providing this does not seem standard in this particular field.

Comment: Maybe the book "Fundamentals of Adaptive Filtering" by Ali H. Sayed answers your questions?

Answer (score 1):

Use separate parallel adaptive filters...one for each noise reference and combine these outputs to subtract from your noisy signal. LMS usually works best but RLS is fine. Problems arise if any of the noise references are heavily correlated with the desired signal.